# How to play video from local folder in django?

Tags: python, django

I am working on Anomaly detection project working with django app. i tried to play video from local folder in django app but stuck. How to play the video?

Comment: i have to open folder then play my video.

Comment: If you know how to serve files using Django, then it's all straight-forward.

Comment: Hi, and welcome to StackOverflow please take some time to read and follow the guidelines of the [How to Ask section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) of the documentation and provide a [minimum, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for the community to try to help you with your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Add this small piece of code to your template, it should do the work for you.

```
{% load staticfiles %} 

<video width="430" height="340" controls autoplay>
  <source src="{% static "video_file_name.mp4" %}" type="video/mp4"> </source> #give your video file name here
</video>
```

```
# Make sure you have copied your video file into your django projects static folder
# And specified static path in settings.py
settings.py

STATICFILES_DIRS = (os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"), )
```